# What is the difference between Ace Attorney Trilogy and Chronicles?

Tags: phoenix-wright-ace-attorney, the-great-ace-attorney-chronicles

I've seen the Ace Attorney Trilogy and also the Ace Attorney Chronicles go on sale recently and I've been trying to understand what separates them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Phoenix Wright: Ace Attorney Trilogy** is a compilation containing remasters of the first 3 games in the *Ace Attorney* series:

- *Phoenix Wright: Ace Attorney*
- *Phoenix Wright: Ace Attorney - Justice for All*
- *Phoenix Wright: Ace Attorney - Trials and Tribulations*

**The Great Ace Attorney Chronicles** is a bundle containing the prequels:

- *The Great Ace Attorney: Adventures*
- *The Great Ace Attorney 2: Resolve*

Comment: Are the chronicles part of the main games? Is there a recommended start point for someone who hasn't played any of the games yet?

Comment: @PerplexingPies Chronicles is a prequel, you take the role of Phoenix's ancestor Ryunosuke Naruhodo. I think it's better to start with the original trilogy, then the prequels because they introduce new gameplay mechanics.

Comment: Still referencing this, great answer thank you!